# Location Service no longer backgrounding

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been using code from [Xamarin's Background Location demo](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/BackgroundLocationDemo) in my app for over a year and never had any issues with background location updates, until about two weeks ago. I'm no longer seeing my logs when the application is in the background from this code below:

**LocationService.cs**

```
#region ILocationListener implementation
        // ILocationListener is a way for the Service to subscribe for updates
        // from the System location Service

        public void OnLocationChanged(Android.Locations.Location location)
        {
            this.LocationChanged(this, new LocationChangedEventArgs(location));

            Log.Debug(logTag, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());

            Log.Debug(logTag, "---- LOCATION UPDATED");

            if (!Settings.IsLoggedIn)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (Settings.IsAuthExpired)
            {
                Task.Run(() => loginStore.Refresh());
            }

            // This should be updating every time we request new location updates
            // both when the app is in the background, and in the foreground
            //Log.Debug(logTag, String.Format("Latitude is {0}", location.Latitude));
            //Log.Debug(logTag, String.Format("Longitude is {0}", location.Longitude));

            Settings.Latitude = location.Latitude;
            Settings.Longitude = location.Longitude;

            Task.Run(() => dataStore.UpdateLocation(location.Latitude, location.Longitude));
        }
```

Here is my manifest file (without the name of my app, etc). I checked through my history and this file has only gone under version number changes for 8 months (so nothing major within the past couple of weeks to warrant an issue with background locations).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="60" android:versionName="0.1.7" package="REDACTED">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY" />
    <application android:label="REDACTED" android:icon="@drawable/logo_size_icon">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="REDACTED.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with this closed Issue on the Xamarin Repo: https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/issues/99